# Android app install counts are not updating

Tags: android, google-play

In google play developer console, It is showing correct app installs.
But when I search my app in play store, It's not updating the install count.

What could be the reason?

eg: My app has 200 installs, when I see in google play developer console.
But when I search my app in google play store, there it shows install 50-100, But It should show 100-500.

I am facing this issue for last 1 week.

Here is the app link
[Get Me Food](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.getmefood.consumer)

Comment: Would you mind linking the app? It could be related to a cache in your device if accessing through the Play Store App. It happened to me more than once that my apps should have triggered an update, but only after entering multiple times, it worked.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.getmefood.consumer
this is the app link,
I tried it with many different mobiles and browser, but the issue is still there.

Comment: Yeah, I also see the 50-100 tier. However, I saw a warning in my play console telling the same @milapTank posted. Could be just a delay issue

Answer (score 0):

hey please look into your google play developer account in announcement section google have some changes in that you can get it from it i am attaching image of it please have look into

[image]

Comment: Thanks milap..... They have mentioned it in their announcement section, but no fix time, when it will be fixed.

Comment: @Neeraj they will inform when they are get fixed :)